# How to combine bands and band ratios using earth engine

Tags: python, multi-band, google-earth-engine

I am trying to display a multispectral image of bands (4,5,6,4/6,6/5) using Landsat8 satellite imagery. I am doing this in Google Earth Engine using Python. I am new to earth engine and python, so I am taking this as an important learning exercise.

For example, I would like something as intuitive as the following to work (where "test" is an image from Landsat8):

```
Image(url=test.getThumbUrl({
         'region':safata_region,
         'bands':'B4,B5,B6,B4/B6,B6/B5'
        }))
```

But it doesn't  (If I were to remove the ratios B4/B6 and B6/B5 it works)

Creating the ratios of bands 4,5, and 6 is simple. For example:

```
A = test.expression(
'RED/SWIR',{
    'RED' : test.select('B4'),        
    'SWIR' : test.select('B6')
    }
)

B = test.expression(
'SWIR/NIR',{
    'NIR' : test.select('B5'),        
    'SWIR' : test.select('B6')
    }
)
```

But I cannot combine this with the other bands in the same fashion as above because A and B are not bands of "test"... I tried finding something similar in Google's fantastic guides, but no luck... Anyone able to give some guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the bands to your image using, for instance, [`addBands`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_composite_mosaic).

```js
var combined = test
               .addBands(A.rename('B4B6'))
               .addBands(B.rename('B5B6'));
```

Comment: Thanks - I am getting closer. But, when I did this, (without the name change), I received the following error:  

`EEException: Image.visualize: Must specify between 1 and 3 bands to visualize.`

This was after the following 

`combined = test.addBands(A).addBands(B)

Image(url=combined.getThumbUrl({
        'region':safata_region,
        'bands':'B4,B5,B6,A,B'
        }))`

Comment: Ah, I see. Your `Image` is for display, not `ee.Image` - which creates multiband images. You need to create the multiband image first as a [server side object](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server). In any case - the visualisation only accepts 3 bands for RGB.